# Anylogic: How to add the choice of route (based on route costs)?

Tags: routes, anylogic, agent, population

In my Anylogic model I added a Java class MyRoute and a function that reads route costs from a database:

```
GISRoute route = main.map.getRoute(
(double) selectFrom(odcosts)
    .where(odcosts.origin.eq(order.terminal.name))
    .uniqueResult(odcosts.latitudeorigin),
(double) selectFrom(odcosts)
    .where(odcosts.origin.eq(order.terminal.name))
    .uniqueResult(odcosts.longitudeorigin),
(double) selectFrom(odcosts)
    .where(odcosts.destination.eq(order.customer.name))
    .uniqueResult(odcosts.latitudedestination),
(double) selectFrom(odcosts)
    .where(odcosts.destination.eq(order.customer.name))
    .uniqueResult(odcosts.longitudedestination), true);
MyRoute myRoute = new MyRoute();
myRoute.route = route;
myRoute.cost = (double) selectFrom(odcosts)
    .where(odcosts.origin.eq(order.terminal.name))
    .where(odcosts.destination.eq(order.customer.name))
    .uniqueResult(odcosts.cost);
```

How can I now add the choice of trucks (when they receive an order) to use:

*A) Direct route between origin and destination at day time*

*B) Route via hub (origin -> hub at night & hub -> destination at day time)*

How do I tell the truck agent population to look at the routes and the costs and make the decision?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually write this information into 1D or 2D Arraylists, depending on the dimension of the input information:
`ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> routes=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();`.
You can remove the lanes that do not meet certain criteria like this:
`routes.removeIf(s -> s.get(0) != "myCustomer");`

Then iterate through the OD information and add the cost of each into an arrayList.

```
List <Float> costs=new ArrayList<Float>();
for (int route_no=0;route_no<routes.size();route_no++) {
            cost=routes.get(route_no);
            costs.add(cost);    
            }
```

Then finding the index of the minimum cost like this:

```
        int indexMin=0;

        for (int i2=0; i2<costs.size(); ++i2) {
            if (min > costs.get(i2)) {
                    min = costs.get(i2);
                    indexMin = i2;
                        }
                }
```

Now you know that the cheapest option's index is indexMin. Then you can do whatever you want with this information.

Comment: Thank you! As I am new to Anylogic (I actually think I need some explanation course on how to implement some pieces of the model ;) ), I was wondering where in the model I should add this code (e.g., as a function or something else)?

Comment: I read the OD data on Main startup section (at time=0), then selection of the cheapest route happens inside an event in the course of the simulation.